# How to make Django's AppConfig ready() run only when serving?

Tags: python, django

I have some Django apps that run background processes when they start.
I use the `ready()` hook method in `apps.py` to trigger them.

What I didn't know is: this method gets executed on every usage of `manage.py`.
For example, I don't want that code to run when just doing migrations.

What could be a proper solution to this?